# The font "LibertinusMaths" cannot be found

Tags: luatex, macos, libertinus, lualatex-dev

Having trouble running the following MWE with LuaLaTeX, despite ***multiple*** confirmations that font-libertinus was successfully installed using Homebrew! I'm running MacOS Ventura 13.3.1 on M2 Max; TeXShop typesetting with LuaLaTeX. The following MWE is enough to generate the error:

> The font "LibertinusMaths" cannot be found.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % this calls fontspec
\setmathfont[]{Libertinus Maths}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

which results in the following error log:

> This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023)   restricted system
> commands enabled. (./font_testing.tex LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level
> 1  L3 programming layer <2023-05-15>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls Document
> Class: book 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk12.clo))
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def))
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-luatex.
> sty
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
> ) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty For
> additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/lualatex-math/lualatex-math.st
> y
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty))
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.t
> ex))) luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc);
> reason: Font "LibertinusMaths" not found. luaotfload | resolve :
> sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.
>
> ./font_testing.tex:4: Package fontspec Error: The font
> "LibertinusMaths" cannot  be found.
>
> For immediate help type H .  ...
>
> l.4 \begin
> {document} ?

I've recently switched from using LaTeX to LuaLaTeX to typeset the code.

Oddly enough, the same code runs w/o error on an older Mac running Catalina 10.15.7 MacOS.

Apologies for the lengthly error log, but I have NO idea what might be needed to diagnose the error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Compiles on  my TL23 system (upsteam) when I use `Libertinus Math` **not** `Libertinus Maths`

Comment: @daleif - OK ... that solves the immediate error of "The font "LibertinusMaths" cannot be found", but my project now errors on "LaTeX Error: Command \Rightarrowfill@ already defined", which was NOT part of my original question. Not your problem, so if you can write your comment as an answer, I can accept to give you credit. Thank you again!!

Comment: The MWE you provide should not give an error like that, so please reduce to a new MWE and post another question. BTW: why didn't you just install MacTeX and not homebrew? Doesn't homebrew cripple `tlmgr` just like Debian does?

Comment: @daleif - I DID install MacTeX. But `Libertinus Maths`, with an 's',  not working so I used Homebrew. Now that I see it working with just `Libertinus Math` I'll try reinstalling MacTeX 2023 and see what happens. Re `homebrew crippling tlmgr`, I have no idea ... you just added to what I have to research ... Thank you! I need to get some sleep so it may take me a bit for a new MWE. In the meantime I'd like to give you credit if you'd like for the answer you already provided. Answer accepted! Thank you!!

Comment: There is a tool to look up the font names. One could be `luaotfload-tool --list=* | sort` it at least lists `Libertinus Math Regular Version 7.040;RELEASE` for me, so no `s`

Comment: @daleif - Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I change

```
\setmathfont[]{Libertinus Maths}
```

to

```
\setmathfont[]{Libertinus Math}
```

the MWE compiles just fine on my (upstream) TeXLive 2023.